Chat meeting #3: Review a book
Announcing our next chat meeting which will take place on Tuesday 28th February 2012 at 19:30 UTC - please adjust for your timezone. You can sign up for reminders in your timezone on the schedule page.
In this chat meeting, as well as any issues you want to raise (feel free to let me know), I propose we do some book reviews/book Q&A. I propose therefore you might want to be in one of two camps:

You're reading a crypto book, or have read one, and would recommend it. Great! Feel free to come along and give us a summary of what the book covers and whether we should spend our hard-earned currency on it! You might want to find an Amazon link for a nice onebox of the image (feel free to ask about this). You might also want to summarise who the book might be suitable for.
You're wondering about a book, and want to know if anyone has read it. Great! Come along and ask!

I propose we split the session into three sections: reviews by those who wish to review, questions, then anything else.
Then, after the session, I will do my best to take the chat history and produce a sane version we can keep around. If this is successful I propose we do it again.
So hopefully I have left enough time for everyone to sign up and be there.

Great idea! I'm still studying and hope this continues when I finish my books

Chat event #3 took place - if you couldn't make it, feel free to check the transcript here.
